# How to disable cardview effect while navigation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I recently updated my iOS version to iOS13, After updating I facing an issue after login, The login screen goes back and the home screen covers **90percent** of the screen and it looks like a cardView can any one help how to show the entire home screen, I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen` to prevent the default card style presentation.

```
let newVC = UIViewController()
newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(newVC, animated: true)
```

**Edit**: Objective-C:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[controller setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:true completion:^{}];
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: for objective C can I get the code.

Comment: Added Objective c code.

Comment: In my case I am using SWRevealViewController .   my code is   SWRevealViewController * myHs = [segue destinationViewController];
  myHs.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;

Answer (score -1):

**For Objective-C users**

```
[vc setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
```

Or if you want to add it particular in iOS 13.0 then use

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
     [vc setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
 } else {
     // Fallback on earlier versions
 }
```

Comment: In my case I am using SWRevealViewController .   my code is   SWRevealViewController * myHs = [segue destinationViewController];
  myHs.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;